# memory leak while making graph of functions in calculator iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory

i am developing a scientific calculator for iPad . I am trying to draw functions creating a graphical representation . but i a have a memory leak when i draw a function of second degree for example x^2 . I was wondering if you could help solve the following memory leak,please? I would appreciate any help.  The button that opens the screen with the function to be drawn has this code :

```
userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = YES;
graphVC.expression =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"$x**2"] ]; 
[self prepareToSolve];
graphVC=[[GraphViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GraphViewController" 
bundle:Nil];
[self presentModalViewController:graphVC animated:YES];
```

Then in the GraphViewController i set the expression with the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[graphView reset];
[graphView setNeedsDisplay];
currentColumn = [NSMutableString string];
substitutions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
eval = [DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator];
[currentColumn setString:[expression objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

and then the method expressionResultForXValue leaks

```
- (double)expressionResultForXValue:(NSNumber*)x requestor:(GraphView *)graphView {
[substitutions setValue:x forKey:@"x"];
return [[eval evaluateString:currentColumn withSubstitutions:substitutions] 
doubleValue]; //[CalculatorBrain evaluateExpression:self.expression 
usingVariableValues:variableValues];
}
```

even though in the viewDidUnload method i set `- [expression release];`
The expressionResultForXValue method is called many times by the UIView GraphView by the drawrect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGPoint midpoint;
midpoint.x = self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width/2 + originOffset.x;
midpoint.y = self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height/2 + originOffset.y;
[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
[AxesDrawer drawAxesInRect:self.bounds originAtPoint:midpoint 
scale:self.scale*self.contentScaleFactor];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
for (CGFloat i = 0; i <= self.bounds.size.width; i++) {
CGPoint nextPointInViewCoordinates;
nextPointInViewCoordinates.x = i;
CGPoint nextPointInGraphCoordinates;
nextPointInGraphCoordinates.x = (nextPointInViewCoordinates.x - midpoint.x)/(self.scale 
* self.contentScaleFactor);
nextPointInGraphCoordinates.y = ([self.delegate expressionResultForXValue:[NSNumber 
numberWithDouble:nextPointInGraphCoordinates.x]
requestor:self]);
nextPointInViewCoordinates.y = midpoint.y - (nextPointInGraphCoordinates.y * self.scale 
* self.contentScaleFactor); 
if (i == 0) {
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, nextPointInViewCoordinates.x, 
nextPointInViewCoordinates.y);
} else {
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 
nextPointInViewCoordinates.x,nextPointInViewCoordinates.y);
}    
}

[[UIColor yellowColor] setStroke];
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

The memory leak i get is :

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
_DDFunctionExpression   1020    < multiple >    15,94 KB    Rechemaschinn    
+[DDExpression functionExpressionWithFunction:arguments:error:]
NSDecimalNumber 1018    < multiple >    15,91 KB    Foundation  -[NSDecimalNumberPlaceholder initWithDecimal:]
_DDNumberExpression 1020    < multiple >    15,94 KB    Rechemaschinn   +[DDExpression numberExpressionWithNumber:]
NSArray 1020    < multiple >    15,94 KB    Rechemaschinn   -[_DDFunctionExpression initWithFunction:arguments:error:]
_DDVariableExpression   1020    < multiple >    15,94 KB    Rechemaschinn   +[DDExpression variableExpressionWithVariable:]
__NSCFString    1019    < multiple >    15,92 KB    Foundation  -[NSPlaceholderString initWithCharacters:length:]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try using instruments?

Comment: yes , but i could not find the reason, these lines are actually taken from Instruments. I tried both with ARC and without ARC , in the second case i get errors and crashes , in the first only leaks.I would appreciate any help.